# np.dot(A,A,A) changes the value of A

Tags: python, numpy

Let A be a fixed matrix in numpy, then after executing the function

```
>> np.dot(A,A,A)
```

the value of A change. I don't understand why this is happening?

The same if I execute for a given matrix B the function

```
>>> np.matmul(B,B,B)
```

then the value of B is setting to zero. Why?

Comment: It's explained in the docs. Hint: ```numpy.dot(a, b, out=None)``` Also: a dot is not a numpy.linalg.multidot.

Comment: By the way, you can chain dot calls: `A.dot(A).dot(A)`

Comment: You can also do np.dot(A,B) as  A.dot(B) with no np  ?

Comment: Compare [np.dot()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html#numpy.dot) with [np.ndarray.dot()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dot.html).